# Is there a list/source of stable kernels?

Tags: suspend, kernel, laptop

I am experiencing the dreaded "wake from suspend" issues that seem endemic to Linux and laptops, and am basically going through a long list of different solutions googling has gotten me to see if they work. One such solution is to downgrade my kernel to a previous version in GRUB and see if that works. I'm currently running 5.4.0-70-generic and Grub gives me the option of booting into 5.4.0-42-generic, which doesn't change the issue; I'd like to download the last several supported kernels and basically just boot into them one after another and see if any of them fix it.
Is there a list somewhere/source of the previous ubuntu kernels that are still supported by elementary?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Mark,

I was experiencing the same issue on my PC (not on laptop). I fixed it but I did not downgrade kernel. What I did I changed some settings on my motherboard (MSI X570)

MSI motherboard has two nice settings:

1. **UEFI HDD BBS Prioretise**: I set default to Ubuntu (previously was Windows 10) (I have both systems on my PC)
2. **Advanced / Wake Up event setup**: I set to BIOS and enabled: **Resume by UBS**, **Resume by Keyboard**, **Resume by Mouse**

But before that - when I tried to wake up my system after suspending I was pressing `CTRL+ALT+F1` and then `CTRL+ALT+F7` few times and it mostly gave me positive results. I was able to start working and I was not forced to restart system.

Now, when I want to suspend Elementary OS I press a `FN+F12` (FN = function key) and to wake up I press just a `PrintScreen` key

Comment: Oh nice!
I actually ended up UPGRADING to a later kernel after finding a mention online that it worked well with my specific laptop, and that helped me. I'm glad to see other solutions!